# Why Input string was not in a correct format and exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, arrays

I am getting an error while taking array input from the user.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] arrSum = new int[] { };
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the array Size:\t");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());            
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the array elements of {0} as Array Size:\n",n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           arrSum[i] = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arrSum[]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number whose sum you want to find:\n");
        int j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        ArraySum(arrSum,n,j);

    }

    public static int ArraySum(int[] arr, int key, int n)
    {                                
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {              
            int first = arr[i];

            for (int k = i+1; k < arr.Length; k++)
            {
                int second = arr[k];
                while (first + second == key)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The numbers whose sum is {0}" + key + "are:\n" + first + second);
                }

                if (first + second != key)
                {
                    return -1;                                               
                }                                     
                else
                {
                    return 1; 
                }                   
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

To take array size and elements and the number whose sum we need to compare among the given array elements from the user as input and return the possible pairs whose sum is equal to the given number.

Comment: `arrSum[i] = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arrSum[]);` That line compiles fine for you? I can't see how it could. https://dotnetfiddle.net/asdIbc

Comment: Does the answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I met the same problem as you, but I modified your code as following. At first I created a safe console readline method for integer that there is no exception thrown if an invalid integer is entered:

```
 private static int GetIntFromInput()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string value = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!int.TryParse(value, out int parsedInt))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid integer! Retry or Ctrl+C to abort program...");
                continue;
            }

            return parsedInt;
        }
    }
```

Then I modified your first method as following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the array Size:\t");
        int n = GetIntFromInput();
        if (n <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Array has to be at least of size 1...");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the array elements of {0} as Array Size:\n", n);

        var arrSum = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int newInt = GetIntFromInput();
            arrSum[i] = newInt;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number whose sum you want to find:\n");
        int j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        ArraySum(arrSum, n, j);
    }
```

With this my tests had been successful. Please note, that I did not replace the last Convert.ToInt32 for j.

As a note, please always verify user input as far as possible for not throwing exceptions. If anytime you will check anything not correctly it will crash sometime for sure...

have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I just have modified your array input code lines, pretty much straight forward. You can use `int.TryParse` as well just in case you wish to have a check

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the array Size:\t");
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());   
int[] arrSum = new int[n];         
Console.WriteLine("Enter the array elements of {0} as Array Size:\n",n);
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    arrSum[i]= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("Enter the number whose sum you want to find:\n");
int j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
ArraySum(arrSum,n,j);
```